# how to change R-code to combine cox proportional hazards model with BDLIMs?

Tags: r

I had read the paper "Bayesian distributed lag interaction models to identify perinatal windows of vulnerability in children’s health". I also tried the R-code from the Github website. I also read the other paper "Prenatal fine particulate exposure and early childhood asthma Effect of maternal stress and fetal sex", and the author also applied BDLIMs to accall for effect modifications by OR. I have been looking for how to convert the y-axis to OR in BDLIMs for a long time, but I have not found it. Furthermore, I want to know how to change the label of the y-axis to OR and change the label of the x-axis to gestational weeks. However, I want to use the cox proportional hazards model to calculate HR in my dataset. Simultaneously, we also want to apply the BDLIMs to examine effect modification by sex. Therefore, could I ask you how to change R-code to combine the cox proportional hazards model with BDLIMs?
My data:
The y-axis is a disease (with and without autism (1,0)) The x-axis is weekly atmosphere mercury exposure. I want to investigate the association between exposure and disease by cox proportional hazards model with BDLIMs.

```
R code:
fit <- bdlim(Y=data$autism,X=lag, Z=data$ID_SEX, G=data$ID_SEX, 
             inter.model="all", niter=100, nthin=5,
             basis.opts = list(df=7, type="bs"),seed=1234)
```

I hope the y-axis is HR, but the actual output is estimated effect